# Build smallest number larger than K using only allowed digits

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given an array containing digits between 0-9 and a number K, find the smallest number built by the digits in the array, such that it is larger than K

For example, if `array = [0,1]` and `K = 21`, the program should return `100`, as `0`, `1` and `10` are smaller than `21`, and `100` is the first number composed only from `zeros` and `ones` that is larger than `21`.

I can think about the brute force method  where I can find all the possible numbers that can be created with the digits in the array and then finding the smallest number greater than K, but I am looking for a more clever and elegant solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is my first question on StackOverflow. I would be really grateful if people who downvote this question also tell me the reason why.

Comment: Always try to provide what you've tried already. We are here to help you solve errors, we are not here to write the code for you.
Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you could improve your question.
Edit: also, try to repeat what you want in your question and not only in the title. Be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Algorithm:**

Let me introduce some variables:

`k_digits` - the number of digits in the number `K`.

First of all, we can observe that our resulting number will have `k_digits` or `k_digits + 1`. If it's not clear yet, I will explain it in more details in the end.

Let's start from assuming that the answer will have the `k_digit` digits.

We can split our main problem into a few smaller (and then receive the answer to the initial problem by combining the solutions to the subproblems). The statement of the subproblem will sound as following:

> 1. What is the smallest number is larger than `K` *WITHOUT* last digit.
> 2. Can we compose the number `K` without last digit from the digits we are allowed to use?

Let's assume we have a solution to both this problem. Then we need to find the answer to the initial problem. We can do this in the following way:

**a)** If the answer to the subproblem 2 is true (we can compose without last digit). Then we should try to add the smallest available digit from the set to the end of that number so it is larger than `K`. What we actually do - we try to replace the last digit of the initial `K` with the larger one from `allowed set`. Let's call this *new number* `answer1`.

**b)** Add the smallest available number from the set to the end of the number from the first subproblem. This number will be larger than `K` as its prefix is larger. Let's call this number `answer2`.

**c)** At the final step we should compare `answer1` (if it exists) and `answer2`, and pick the smallest. This will be the answer to the initial question.

Well, now I hope it is clear how we combine the answer from the subproblems.
So, now I will explain how to find the solution to the subproblems.

Let's start from the **second subproblem**. It is easy - we just check if we have in our `allowed set` all digits of the number `K` (without last one).

Now the **first subproblem**. You may notice that this subproblem is equal to the initial problem, but with smaller `K`. So, we can solve this "recursively". The base case here will be single-digit `K`. We can say the answer directly, when we have only one digit - just to search our set for the digit larger the digit of the `K`.

Also, notice, at some point we may not have the answer to the subproblem 1. This means that we cannot compose the number of length `k_digits` that is larger than `K`. But, in this case, we can always compose the number with `k_digits + 1`. Just to select the smallest digit from the allowed set    `(k_digits + 1)` times. ***Special case: zeros.***

**Example:**

```
allowed_set=[4,5]
K = 435
```

We can see that we can spit our initial problem to subproblem, where `K = 43`.
The solution to the second subproblem will be `false` as we aren't allowed to use digit `3`. The solution to the first subproblem we will try to find in the following way - splitting this again to the two subproblems, where `K = 4`. In this case, the answer to the first subproblem will be `5`, and to the second subproblem will be `4`. We can compose the answer to the case `K = 43` as following: `answer1 = 44`, `answer2 = 54`. The `answer1` is smaller, so, this is actually the answer to the case when `K = 43`. Then, to find the answer for `K = 435` we only can add the `4` to the end of the `44`. So, the answer is `444`.

It may be not the best example, but I hope it illustrates my answer. Ask, if you have any additional comments.

Comment: This is just what I wanted. Can't believe I missed the recursive nature of the solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Can you build a number that's equal to the given one except for the last digit that is bigger, yes?

No?, then, can you build a number that's equal to the given one except that the tens digit that is bigger?

Etc...

Comment: Isn't this going to take way too many traversals over the array of digits?

Comment: I am not providing you the best solution but just a starting point... it should be easy to progress from there!

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new at programming myself, about 4 months of experience with C++ and we were given an assignment quite similar to this as one of our homework problems, hope this helps!

```
//given array A of usable digits and assuming it is sorted
//meaning A[1] is the smallest

ans = 0;

//first we find the digits of K
//we use {} as Gauss
K_digits = {log(K)} + 1
numleft = K;
for i = 1 to K_digits
    B[i] = {numleft/(10^(K_digits - i))}
    numleft = numleft - B[i]*10^(K_digits - i)

//next we search through the array K_digits times
Max_seq = A[A.length] // max number in array
min_seq = A[1] // min number in array
usebigger = 0  // if this equals 1, we need to add an extra digit than K to be larger than K
copy = 0 //number of digits to copy, starting from left side

j = 1
while (j <= K_digits)
    if Max_seq < B[j]
        usebigger = 1
        j = K_digits + 1 // end while loop
    else if Max_seq == B[j]
        copy = copy + 1
        j = j + 1
    else if Max_seq > B[j] 
        for t = 1 to A.length
            if B[j] < A[t]
            value = A[t]
            break;
        j = K_digits + 1

if copy == K_digits // can only manage to find a same valued number
    usebigger = 1


//finally, with this info, we find the answer
if usebigger == 1 // need to add an extra digit than K to be larger than K
    if min_seq == 0
        for s = 1 to A.length
            if A[s] > 0
            min_num = A[S]
            break;
        ans = min_num*(10^K_digits)
    else
        for x = 0 to K_digits
            ans = ans + min_seq*(10^x)    

else
    if copy != 0
        for i = 1 to copy
            ans = ans + B[i]*(10^(K_digits - i))
    ans = ans + value*(10^(K_digits - copy - 1))

    if copy+2 <= K_digits
        for y = copy+2 to K_digits
            ans = ans + min_seq*(10^(K_digits - y))

return ans
```